# Load empty value from model to Label in Laravel 5 Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to display a empty string from Model to html control in Laravel 5 Blade template.

> {!!
>   Form::label('labelOccupation',$mastermodel->occupation,['style'=>'background-color:#BCBCBC'])
>   !!}
>
> {!!
>   Form::text('textOccupation',$mastermodel->occupation,['style'=>'background-color:#BCBCBC'])
>   !!}

Both the text and label control can display value of occupation field correctly. But when the value is an empty string, the label control will display the wording "occupation", while the text control still able to show as empty.

Does it means I have to check empty string exists in Model every time when loading the value into label? Any other easier methods to handle such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way on your controller before passing the label on the form:

```
if(empty($mastermodel->occupation) {
    $occupation_label = 'occupation';
} else {
    $occupation_label = $mastermodel->occupation;
}
```

Then pass it to use in your blade:

```
{!! Form::label('labelOccupation',$occupation_label,['style'=>'background-color:#BCBCBC']) !!}
```

I think it's the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes that is the straightforward solution. In that case, I will check empty with shorthand if in blade template, so that I don't have to pass variables to blade one by one. Anyway I would like to see if there is solution so that I don't have to write a set of check empty string logic every time when I work with another new Model.

Comment: For the goal of avoid check empty string everytime, I achieve it by replace label control with text control and set it to readonly. {!! Form::text('textOccupation',$mastermodel->occupation,['style'=>'background-color:#BCBCBC','readonly']) !!}